# How to remove non-INTERNATIONAL-alphanumeric characters from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

How can I remove (or recognize) non-alphanumeric characters such as `'-', '*', '‡', '€', '⁋', '™'` from a string ***without removing non-Latin*** alphanumeric characters such as `'Ж', 'ק', 'ओ', 'を'`?

The removing part is easy, my issue is differentiating the non-Latin alphabets from the non-Latin symbols.

* All existing Q&A I found filtered out non-Latin alphabets.

Comment: How will your text be normalised? You say that you want to exclude `™`, does that include other letter-like symbols that normalise into "alphanumeric" characters (like `㍇`, `Ⅽ`, `㎏`, `⒜`)?

Comment: @一二三 I have a normalization stages before that include replacing white-space with spaces, changing characters like `ﬁ` into `fi` and `Ä` into `A` and converting upper case Latin to lower case. I doubt that the normalizing into `NormalizationForm.FormKD`, ingoring `UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark`, then normalizing into `NormalizationForm.FormC` covers all the cases, however, it is better than nothing. In addition, I do perform transliteration into Latin, however, I also process the string in the original alphabet and the non-alpha numeric symbols shouldn't be included in my processing.

Comment: @一二三, would the .IsLetterOrDigit() recognize `一二三` as digits?

Comment: It recognises them as letters; .NET doesn't support them as numbers. Similarly, `½` and `⑸` are "other numbers" and are recognised by `IsNumber()` but not `IsDigit()` (although, both decompose into sequences with digits).

Comment: @一二三 Works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8bl0oz

Comment: Why would someone vote down this question or the (correct) selected answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution (that works only for basic BMP characters) is:

```
string str = "-*‡€⁋™Жקओを";

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char ch in str)
{
    bool isLetter = char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch);

    if (isLetter)
    {
        sb.Append(ch);
    }
}

string str2 = sb.ToString();
```

The [`Char.IsLetterOrDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cay4xx2f.aspx) is described as:

> Indicates whether the specified Unicode character is categorized as a letter or a decimal digit.

if you want to support surrogate pairs it becomes more complex:

```
// \U0001F000 is MAHJONG TILE EAST WIND
// \U0001D49E is MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL C
string str = "-*‡€⁋™Жקओを\U0001F000\U0001D49E";

var sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    bool isLetter = char.IsLetterOrDigit(str, i);

    bool isHighSurrogate = char.IsHighSurrogate(str[i]);

    if (isLetter)
    {
        sb.Append(str, i, isHighSurrogate ? 2 : 1);
    }

    if (isHighSurrogate && i + 1 < str.Length && char.IsLowSurrogate(str[i + 1]))
    {
        i++;
    }
}

string str2 = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I see that it is important to use `char.IsLetterOrDigit(str, i)` and **not** `char.IsLetterOrDigit(str[i])`, does it matter if you use `char.IsHighSurrogate(str[i])` or `char.IsHighSurrogate(str, i)` (and same for `IsLowSurrogate`)? (Initial tests show that is isn't, but I want to be sure.)

Comment: @danny By definition a high/low surrogate is a single `char`, so it isn't important... And if you look inside the `IsHighSurrogate(string s, int index)` it does exactly: `return char.IsHighSurrogate(s[index]);` (plus some checks about the arguments)

Comment: @xanatox thanks. The different results for `char.IsLetterOrDigit(str, i)` and `char.IsLetterOrDigit(str[i])` surprised me - I understood from them that the pair of HighSurrogate and LowSurrogate is considered as a character, but not if you look at the first position separately.

Comment: @DannyVarod A High+Low surrogate is called a surrogate *pair* for a reason... If they aren't together, they are nothing. You can't look at one of them and "desume" information about the other.